# will_paginate don't take WillPaginate::ViewHelpers.pagination_options[:renderer] in consideration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I've done a custom LinkRenderer. It works fine when used like:

```
<%= will_paginate @results, :renderer => PaginationRenderer %>
```

But putting this in an initializer does not work:

```
WillPaginate::ViewHelpers.pagination_options[:renderer] = 'PaginationRenderer'
```

or even

```
WillPaginate::ViewHelpers.pagination_options[:renderer] = PaginationRenderer
```

If I print `WillPaginate::ViewHelpers.pagination_options[:renderer]` when rails has booted, it answers me the correct `PaginationRenderer`.

It seems that it does not use it at rendering time. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it was removed, see https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/commit/3c1225168ea7c583dfe6b897fe52131f1c06e878

Comment: Thanks ! So i've wrapped a `will_paginate :renderer => MyRenderer` call in an helper.